# Can't locate a brush stage on layers panel in order to change the color

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, layers, brush

I am making a design for my website in Photoshop. I want to change the color of the spray brush I painted with many stages ago but I cannot find that stage on the layers panel. How can I change the color?

Answer (score 1):

I found my own answer! The paint layer was for some reason together on different shape layer. I can use the erase tool. And I can paint the brush from new. Thanks, this is a very useful forum!